# How do I reference another object's properties in javascript?

Tags: javascript

reference : http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js?r=110

I want to use the markers_ array contents from the MarkerCluster class in the ClusterIcon class at 817 line in the above library.

How do I do that?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What have you tried? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.cluster_.markers_[0]
```

Cluster has a copy of markers array.

Answer (score 0):

can't you Prototype it to expose it?

```
MarkerClusterer.prototype.GetMarkers = function() { return this.markers_; }
```